# Accessing presentation layer while animation is ongoing crashes

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have a simple animation to rotate a view in my app:

```
let rotationAnimation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
myView.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
```

I am trying to find the current status (angle) of the animation while animation is happening. I planned to use a `Timer` like this:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.checkAngle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

and checkAngle is as following:

```
@objc func checkAngle() {
    if let presLayer = self.myView.layer.presentation() {
        print("presLayer exists!")
     }           
}
```

However, I get a crash when evaluating the line where presentation layer is obtained. Here is the crash log:

`2019-08-04 15:22:25.101122-0700 MyView[40772:13461590] -[NSConcreteValue doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000021e1180
2019-08-04 15:22:25.105561-0700 MyView[40772:13461590] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteValue doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000021e1180'`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong or how to periodically check the rotation angle? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @matt but I don't see animation when I used simply transform:  `let toValue = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(rotationAngle))
        rotationAnimation.toValue = toValue // NSNumber(value: rotationAngle )`

Comment: I think I've found it. I was setting the `fromValue` to a transform and `toValue` to a NSnumber. Making both the same unit fixed the problem.

Comment: Should I delete this question or should I answer myself with detail?

Comment: I've deleted my answer to make way for yours, if you have time to give it. Thanks!